# Usage of Modules and stratégie du petit r with navbarPage

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinymodules, golem

I try to understand the usage of modules and stratégie du petit r.
I would like to receive feedback if I used the components correctly?
Also I'm interested: Does it make sense to structure an application in the way that each tabPanel is 1 Module? For Example File Upload, Overview, Clustering, and Reporting.

For this, I built a small application.
A navBarpage with 2 panels. For each tabPanel one module exists which creates the UI and contains the server logic for the panel.

tabPanel 1 / Module "something"

- numeric Input -> user can choose between 1,2,3
- action button. When pressed the panel View changes.

tabPanel 2 / Module "happend"

- shows the chosen number

1. app_ui (UI-structure and calls module UI)
2. server_ui (calls Module Servers)
3. mod_something (Numberinput and actionButton to change panel)
4. mod_happend ( Displays number)

`

**app_ui**

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    # Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    # Your application UI logic
    fluidPage(
      navbarPage("navBarPage",
                 id = "navBarID",
                 tabPanel("title1",
                          mod_something_ui("something_1")),
                 tabPanel("title2",
                          mod_happend_ui("happend_1")),
      )
    )
  )
}
```

**app_server**

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Your application server logic
  r <- reactiveValues()
  #mod_Navigation_server("navigation1",r)
  mod_something_server("something_1", r = r,parent = session)
  mod_happend_server("happend_1",r)
  #?moduleServer
}
```

**mod_something**

```
mod_something_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(inputId = ns("numberInput"), label = "choose", choices = c(1,2,3)),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("doSomething"),label = "Change Page!"),

  )
}

mod_something_server <- function(id,r,parent){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      r$numberInput <- input$numberInput
    })
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$doSomething,
                 updateNavbarPage(session = parent, inputId = "navBarID", selected = "title2"))

  })
}
```

**mod_happend**

```
mod_happend_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  p("the Number is"),
  textOutput(ns("choosenNumber")),
  )
}

#' happend Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_happend_server <- function(id,r){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    number <- reactive(r$numberInput)
    output$choosenNumber <- renderText(number())

  })
}
```

`